# SharePoint group sync with Outlook group

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook

Is it possible to keep a SharePoint group in sync with the an outlook group? So that owner of the site doesn't have to make changes in both places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short answer:  Unfortunately , it's not possible ,

You can sync contact,calendar and task list with outlook but there is no way to sync groups that because of There is a major **design and functionalty** difference between SharePoint Group and the People contacts group in outlook.

Also if you cheked the defination of each group below, you will know why you can't perform group sync !

- `Outlook Contact Group`  is grouping of email addresses collected under one name. (**Note**: you can't create a Contact Group at contact list synced from SharePoint Contact list that due to design too for more details check [contact group sync error](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dirservices/outlook-2013-contact-groups-disappear-in/60c8bdd9-cf9f-450c-a0c2-e881271f6874))
- `SharePoint Group` is a collection of users that have specific permission role like Contribute role , the Read role Design role, Full Control role ..etc.